# Talend Cloud Studio : Issue with look up mapping

Tags: talend

Good day,

I’m new with Talend Cloud Studio and I’m getting stuck with the job I’m working on.

Context:

My company uses an API directory (Genesys). So far, we use a .csv file to insert / update contacts. This file is generated from a database extract.

We want to automatize this process with a Talend Job.

(A) is my Contacts database extract.

(B) is my API (feeded from A) and used as look up component.

Because there is not a unique field that we can use like a proper foreign key between (A) and (B), we map most of (A) fields to (B)’s so input datas can be « filtered » and redirected to two disctincs output « Inserted » and « Updated ».

[Please find my schema attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97LN3.png)

My issue is the following : I know for a fact that 9 rows should be considered as "to be inserted" and one row should be considered as "to be updated",yet, every output are considered as « inserted » (aka new contacts in the directory) and not « updated ».

[Please find my result attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD4Mz.png)

If anyone as any clue about what’s happening or need more details, feel free to ask me !

Thanks by advance for your help.

Regards

Comment: In order to have data in the "Update" output, it means that all fields used for the inner join between A and B input should be the same.   I don't understand your statement : "despite differences between data in (A) and (B), every output are considered as « inserted »" . Indeed, if there are differences between A and B, this would be considered as an "INSERT" output, given that Inner join would not be matched.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 

My statement was a (misleading it seems) way to say "I know for a fact that 9 rows  should be considered as "to be inserted" and one row should be considered as "to be updated"). 

I will update my original message and try your advise.